# How to set surficeview automaticly to display size?

Tags: java, android

i got this surficeview

```
<SurfaceViewandroid:id="@+id/videoview"android:layout_width="720px"android:layout_height="480px"/>
```

how can i manage that set the size automaticly to display size?
Because every android phone has another display size?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to catch it in onSurfaceCreated() and try to resize it there...

```
  private class surfaceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        if (holder == videoHolder)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "video surfaceChanged: f: " + format + ", w: " + width + ", h: " + height);

            //resize it here maybe?
        } else
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unknown surface: f: " + format + ", w: " + width + ", h: " + height);
            assert (false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");
    }
}
```

one possible way to get your display size...

```
    //measured android resolution
    WindowManager win = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display d = win.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point measuredResolution = new Point();
    d.getSize(measuredResolution); //measuredResolution now holds actual size.
```

Comment: but i have a button so i dont want it to to fill the hole display.i just have to get the displaysize-200px?

Comment: if you know your button sizes then yea. otherwise just use displaySize - button.getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight()

Answer (score 1):

You defining this in xml ? then use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` and same in parent container :)

Else if doing this programmatically then see @Shark 's answer

Comment: i tried to do this maybe it works: public void class onCreate(...){...Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();  
        int height = display.getHeight();  
        surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(width, height);
...}